# Positioning AndroidSlidingUpPanel to a specific height

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, android-sliding, bottom-up

I am exploring https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel library. When I slide the bottom panel, on slide complete it acquires complete screen area.

Can anyone help me, How to stop the bottom panel to a certain height, for e.g. slide it till middle of screen??

Comment: i currently have the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using **setAnchorPoint(float)**?

From the DemoActivity in the SlidingUpPanelDemo project

```java
SlidingUpPanelLayout layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
layout.setAnchorPoint(0.3f);
```

this will make the panel slide to 30% of the screen height.

Comment: Did the anchor point setting work ?? I couldn't restrict the sliding by setting anchor point.

Comment: it works but only the half of the bottom panel is showing. is there any solution for resizing the bottom panel according to the change in slideup panel

Answer (score 4):

+1 to @Guilio Prina Ricotti answer.
To make it work, after you call

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
layout.setAnchorPoint(0.3f);
```

in the code, which triggers your slidind layout (for example, onClickListener), instead of calling `slidingLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);`
call

```
slidingLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED);
```

Also don't forget to make your sliding component's height to be `match_parent`

Comment: I wanted to ask one thing, I used the `setAnchorPoint(0.5f)` method to anchor the sliding panel to a half the screen height, upwards .but when I start dragging the panel upwards then it moves  upwards.My requirement is that I don't want to slide the panel upwards, I only want the layout to be anchored to half the screen as I drag up and when I drag it down then it should take the panel downwards

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal, have you found a solution, i also have the same requirment but cant seams to get it work that way

Comment: I', afraid you'll have to use another library or write your own component for that. I didn't find a way to make it.

Answer (score 4):

yo can add 
`android:layout_weight="0.85"`

to your second child of SlidingUpPanelLayout

Comment: I know it's late but this helped!

Comment: @revipod I am glad it helped you